# Is it possible to view a long position broken down by tax lots in Interactive Brokers?

Tags: united-states, fidelity, interactive-brokers, tax-loss-harvesting

In my Fidelity account, positions can be viewed broken down by tax lots as follows:
[image]

I find this incredibly useful when selling securities, because it makes tax-harvesting and other tax saving strategies really easy to execute.

Is there anything like this available in Interactive Brokers?

I am aware of the "Tax Optimizer" tool, but that requires you to sell your positions **before** being able to assign the sale to specific tax lots. I would like to simply view my tax lots **before** selling, so that I can figure out how much to sell from what tax lots to realize a desired amount of long and short term capital gains/losses.

Answer (score 1):

Like Fidelity, Vanguard does it the same way and I too find it easy to execute. OTOH, Interactive Brokers makes this utterly  complex.

I looked at this some time back and my take was that it might be possible using their Tax Optimizer and selecting Specific Lots as the choice.  Here's a 4 minute [VIDEO](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=45672) that  describes it.   At about 2:20 it describes Specific Lots.  That's about as far as I ever went because it seemed like the configuration had to be done every days and while it got you to the same place, it took excessive time and effort.

The best answer is to call tech support.